# XSLT getting value from attribute & modifying other attribute values

Tags: xslt

I've been banging my head on this for a bit now and can't seem to find out how to do this.

I have the following XML like block:

```
<xml>
    <node id="1">
        <item>2</item>
    </node>
    <node id="3">
        <item>4</item>
    </node>
    <special id="5">
        <item>6</item>
    </special>
    <node id="7">
        <item>8</item>
    </node>
    <node id="9">
        <item>10</item>
    </node>
    <node id="11">
        <item>12</item>
    </node>
</xml>
```

What I need to do is find the value of the "id" attribute for the "special" node.  From there I then need to decrment any "id" attributes that are larger than the "special" one by the difference between the special "id" and the higher value and then drop the "special" node.  So the example output would be:

```
<xml>
    <node id="1">
        <item>2</item>
    </node>
    <node id="3">
        <item>4</item>
    </node>
    <node id="5">
        <item>8</item>
    </node>
    <node id="7">
        <item>10</item>
    </node>
    <node id="9">
        <item>12</item>
    </node>
</xml>
```

I know how to drop the "special" node, I thought I understood getting the variable, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

I'm using XSLT 1.0, here's what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="myvar" select="//special/@id"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--drop special-->
    <xsl:template match="//special">
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- this is totally not working, what am I doing wrong? -->
    <xsl:template match="//node/@id">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current() &gt; myvar">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'-1'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit - Clarifying the decrement comment:
Sorry, it was late and apparently I wasn't clear with the updating other ids and I tried to simplify my case too much to provide as simple of an example as I could.  Apparently, I went too simple and got myself turned around.
I need the difference between the first larger ID and the ID I'm removing and then I need to subtract that difference from all IDs greater than the "special" one.  So the first ID that gets updated will change to 5, the second ID that gets updated will go to 7 and then 9, etc.  I have updated the example XML input and desired output.

Comment: Please clarify this: *" I then need to decrment any "id" attributes that are larger than the "special" one by the difference between the special "id" and the higher value"*. In my arithmetic, the result will be always equal to the value of the  special id.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly "decrment any "id" attributes that are larger than the "special" one by the difference between the special "id" and the higher value"? Is that just a complicated way of saying "replace the value of the 'id' attribute with the value of the special 'id'"?

Comment: I have updated the post to clarify the decrement comment hopefully.

Comment: I am afraid you have not added any clarity to what you said earlier. `b - (b - a) = a`. So **any** id that is larger than the $myvar variable will end up being equal to $myvar. If there is more than one, you will end up with duplicate ids.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I have updated the update >_<

Comment: Can one assume that there is only one `special` element and that the first `node` element with the larger `id` is its immediately following sibling?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, there is only 1 special node value and all subsequent IDs following will be larger and they need to have their IDs reduced by the difference between the first larger id and the special ID...if that makes sense....hopefully the example I updated above is more clear.

Comment: Good, so I believe my answer given below should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be assumed that all `id` values in the source XML are in ascending order (and that there will be exactly one `special` element), you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- nodes preceding special -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="special/preceding-sibling::node"/>
        <!-- nodes following special -->
        <xsl:variable name="tail" select="special/following-sibling::node" />
        <xsl:variable name="diff" select="$tail[1]/@id - special/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$tail">
            <node id="{@id - $diff}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

In XSLT 2.0+ I would use the rule

```
<xsl:template match="node/@id[number(.) > $myvar]">
  <xsl:attribute name="id" select="$myvar"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: "//" at the start of a match pattern is nearly always a waste of space.

Note: putting the condition in a match pattern always feels like better coding style than having a template rule whose immediate content is an xsl:choose.

In 1.0, as always, it's a little bit more wordy, because you can't reference global variables in match patterns. So I would write instead:

```
<xsl:template match="node/@id[number(.) > number(//special/@id)]">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="$myvar"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

(except that you wouldn't find me actually writing XSLT 1.0 unless I was desperate...)

I'm reading *decrment any "id" attributes that are larger than the "special" one by the difference between the special "id"* as a rather obscure way of saying *if the id value is larger than the special one then replace it with the special one*.

Comment: I doubt very much they would want more than one node with the same id.

Comment: One can only speculate.

Comment: One can wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Sorry it was late and apparently I wasn't clear with the updating other ids...
So, any IDs that are larger than the variable I need to set to
current_id - (current_id - myvar).  
So, if current ID is 7 and myvar is 5, the new ID would be 
7 - (7 - 5) = 5.

Comment: The formula `x - (x - y)` simplifies to `y`.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I have updated the update to improve the example and what it is I'm after. Hopefully the output explains better than I can in words.

Comment: Downvoted, I assume, because I answered the question as written, and not the question as intended. Ah well, I have a thick skin and plenty of reputation to spare for such things.